# MSI GS70, Blank or misplaced UI elements after upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, gui, windows-installer

I just updated my laptop from Windows 10 (not threshold 2) from Windows 8.1. But I noticed the following ui issues happened on some of the software that I use (Blizzard Battle.net app, Last.fm app, transmission-qt, smplayer and Virtualbox VM). When it happens, I can click on the button and scrollbar and they actually responses, but just not show the result until I close (clicking "OK" or "Cancel") the ui frame.

[image: Dropdown context menu]

[image: misplaced editbox and scrollbar]

These issues don't happened on my surface 3. I used sfc tool under cmd and it saids no corrupted system files found. I also tried refresh fonts cache, but it didn't help.

My laptop is MSI GS70 (Haswell version) with graphics card nvidia gtx 970m (optimus driver). Reinstallation of both intel and nvidia graphics drivers didn't solve the issues either.

Anyone encounter this kind of issue or have any clue of what might causes it?

Comment: maybe a DPI scaling issue. which DPI scaling option do you now use?

Comment: Hello, @magicandre1981. I am using 100% scaling. The problem does not happens immediately everytime I launch those apps but after those apps run for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the cause of the problem. I tried reinstalling the system several times and ruling out every possible driver or system utility provided by the manufacturer that causes the problem (My laptop model is GS70 by MSI, haswell model). Every time I installed a driver or a utility, I tested smplayer to see whether the stated problem occurs. In the end, I found out that after I installed an audio system utility call Nahimic and restart, the problem occured. But it disappeared after I uninstall that Nahimic. Hope this will help everyone comes to this question.

Comment: I've just went through this nightmare. Nahimic seem to be causing UI issues for other applications especially those that are built for cross-platform use, based on Python and QT. Have you filed a bug report?